# Laravel with wirecard payment gateway

Tags: laravel, wirecard

I have no idea how to integrate wirecard payment gateway with laravel I found GitHub libraries that I didn't found useful at all. If you have any experience with such a problem please comment here with regards

Answer (score 1):

1. I think this would be helpful https://github.com/wirecard/paymentSDK-php
2. try to read the General Information section located on that same page, and then see installation and configuration requirements - https://github.com/wirecard/paymentSDK-php/wiki/Installation
3. Feel Free to check example code usage/Sample - https://wirecard.github.io/paymentSDK-php/examples/

Comment: Thanks for your help. But all the libraries that on GitHub don't use seamless mode I found the solution here https://document-center.wirecard.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#Sofort.withWPP-CompleteFieldList&RequestStructure